# Symfony3 - Get Container in EntityRepository

Tags: php, containers, symfony

I got some trouble while accessing the container insinde an EntityRepository

My services.yml

```
services:
    app.event_repository:
        class: Test\MyTestBundle\Repository\EventRepository
        factory: ["@doctrine", "getRepository"]
        arguments: ["MyTestBundle:Event"]
        calls:
            - ["setContainer", ["@service_container"]]
```

And my Repository

```
class EventRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getSomething($id)
    {
        var_dump($this->container);die(); // returns null
    }

...
```

When I try to access th container, it is always "null". I know there are some equal questions, but I still can't find a solution for my problem.

It seems that the method "setContainer()" is never called.

PS: I use Symfony3

Comment: Replace ATdoctrine with ATdoctrine.orm.entity_manager. The usual caveat applies, don't pass the container unless you really really need it.  Best to inject only the services you need.  I am also assuming that you are actually pulling the repository from the container and not using $em->getRepository directly.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate and the linked suggested answer is not applicable.  The title may be a bit misleading but the problem here is that the repository service is defined incorrectly.  Plus, the various linked answers are just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use this :

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class EventRepository extends EntityRepository implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getSomething($id)
    {
        var_dump($this->container);die(); // returns null
    }

...
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not change anything.

The ContainerAwareInterface is just an interface without any logic.